# Transformation of distorted random sequences produces random sequences?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

My program generates what might be called switch(x) sequences.

Here's a description the algorithm that produces them:

```
# define a switch(x) sequence of length n^2
def switch(x):
    s = []                                     # define a bit string s:
    s.append(random.choice([True, False]))     # set its first bit randomly,
    for i in range(1, n * n):                  # but for every subsequent bit i,
        prior = s[i-1]                         # find its prior bit i-1,
        shouldSwitch = x > random.random()     # and with probability 1-x,
        if shouldSwitch: s.append(not prior)   # set i to opposite of its prior;
        else: s.append(prior)                  # otherwise, have i = its prior.
    return s
```

At x = .5, the sequence is thought to be a perfectly random sequence of bits. Deviating x distorts this randomness by producing sequences that either alternate or repeat bits too often.

I produced a program that computed the average alternation rate of a produced switch(x) sequence.

```
r = 0.0
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i] != s[i+1]:
        r = r + 1
rate = r/(len(s)-1)
```

Of course, I always obtain a rate relatively close to x when I put a switch(x) sequence through it, whatever x is. Like, within 1/100ths.

But suppose I transform my produced switch(x) sequence like so (where len(s) = n*n):

```
s1 = switch(x)
s2 = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        s2.append(s1[i + j*n])
```

Whenever I calculate the alternation rate for sequences transformed in this way, I always obtain a value really close to .5! The consistency is scary.

That doesn't make much sense to me, especially for values of x that are very close to 0 or 1. So I was hoping you could help me figure out what's going wrong.

Sorry if something's terrible about my style/efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability for a single flip is `x`, and we consider comparing values that are 2 steps apart in the sequence, we have (where `F` is a flip and `N` is not flipped):

```
P(FF) = x*x
P(NN) = (1-x)*(1-x)
P(FN) = x*(1-x)
P(NF) = (1-x)*x
```

In the first two cases, the two values will be equal while in the second two they will be different. So,

```
P(equal) = P(FF) + P(NN) = x*x + (1-x)*(1-x)
P(different) = P(FN) + P(NF) = x*(1-x) + (1-x)*x = 2x*(1-x)
```

So for a value `x = 0.25` say, we have

```
P(equal) = 0.25*0.25 + 0.75*0.75 = 0.625
P(different) = 2 * 0.25 * 0.75 = 0.375
```

Which is closer to `0.5` than the `x` we started with. I suspect that with values further apart then 2, this would start to approach 0.5 as you are seeing.